# How to reuse animations in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

Is there a way to reuse the same animation in a more pretty way?

```
<a-entity channel-selection class="channels" mixin="fontplane" material="opacity:0.6">
  <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to="0"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="unfade" to="0.6"></a-animation>
  <a-entity class="channels" mixin="channelfont" text="text: Channel6">
    <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to="0"></a-animation>
    <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" begin="unfade" to="0.6"></a-animation>
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways.

One: you can use mixins on a-animation:

```
<a-mixin id="fade" attribute="material.opacity" begin="fade" to="0"></a-mixin>
<a-mixin id="fade" attribute="material.opacity" begin="unfade" to="0.6"></a-mixin>
<a-entity channel-selection class="channels" mixin="fontplane" material="opacity:0.6">
      <a-animation mixin="fade"></a-animation>
      <a-animation mixin="unfade"></a-animation>

      <a-entity class="channels" mixin="channelfont" text="text: Channel6">
        <a-animation mixin="fade"></a-animation>
        <a-animation mixin="unfade"></a-animation>
      </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
```

There's also the [animation component with mixins](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation) or [aframe-mss (mixin stylesheet format)](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-mss), but unfortunately there's some bugs relating to mixins with components that can have multiple instances.

Two: the [template component](https://ngokevin.github.io/kframe/components/template/) can work too

```
  <head>
  <title>My A-Frame Scene</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ngokevin/aframe-template-component/dist/aframe-template-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <script id="fadeAnimations" type="text/html">
        <a-animation></a-animation>
        <a-animation></a-animation>
      </script>
    </a-assets>

    <a-entity template="src: #fadeAnimations">
      <a-entity template="src: #fadeAnimations"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
   </a-scene>
```